# App Store rejected application which is not supporting for iPad even its support for only iPhone

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted two applications **(with minimum version for one is 9.0 and another is 10.0)** which are support for iPhone, but apple guys are rejected because the design is not support for iPad(for iPhone4 resolution) where iPhone4 itself not having version support.

Can anyone guide me if I am going wrong?

Comment: Add Apple rejection message.

Comment: Same happened to me yesterday, I ended up fixing UI and re-uploading the build

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @DavidW
Someone has down voted... I don't know who they are.... Its better to edit the question rather than down voting. It shows your attitude here. And thanks for knowing this. 
I don't know how to move... if you know better... please edit this question and put in proper place so that I will get solution. Don't waste time for down voting...

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that If you don't support 3.5inch devices it will be rejected by apple. It has nothing to do with your iOS version and iPhone4. Because iPad can run all the apps from app store even if they are only for iPhone. iPad will try to run the iPhone only apps in 3.5inch which happens to be the same size of iPhone4 or 4s screen size again 3.5inch remember. Try to check your constraints and that everything fits nicely in small screen size then resubmit your app.

I still always tries to provide the 1x assets which helps a lot even I know my app will be for retina devices but in case of iPad tests it helps a lot.
remember app thinning so no worry about the size of your project each device will be downloading the respective asset types.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Appeal the rejection and write "This does not support iPads as I checked the iPhone only tick box in my project's settings, so please test on an iPhone.". I wrote that, and they accepted the next day.

Answer (score 0):

They are testing if it supports 3.5 inch devices. Make sure your app supports the same.